# problem when reinstall apache2 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, localhost

I had some problem when reinstall `apache2`.

I use:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-bin
```

and then error with this messages,

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvarsinvoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed
```

I try to purge use this:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

after that I try to reinstall again use this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This is message when I try to reinstall apache2 use that code:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom apache2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 405 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/87,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 473 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
(Reading database ... 170080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Enabling module mpm_event.
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what dpkg complaining about,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

try to run the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
```

then run,

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Synaptic Package Manager: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/.

Search for the `apache2` package and choose the option "complete uninstallation". It should purge all the directories and packages that `apache2` configured. Then install the `apache2` package either using the console or from Synaptic Package Manager.