# apt-get fails to upgrade packages

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, package-management

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Server:

```
user@host:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

My issue is this:  When I go to upgrade packages (specifically looking for php5, but it happens for many/most/all) this is what I get:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-suexec-custom : Depends: apache2-bin but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.


user@host:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnet-xwhois-perl libtommath0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/953 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3576 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 95668 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to resolve these errors?  I'd really like to get a PHP version newer than **5.3**, since I have multiple items that require PHP v5.4 minimum.

**NOTE:** I am not trying to fix the locale issue, I'm trying to fix the dpkg error.  This server has always had a locale issue, and it's completely separate. Sorry, but this ain't no duplicate.

Edits for added code:

```
user@host:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-suexec-custom:
 apache2-suexec-custom depends on apache2-bin; however:
  Package apache2-bin is not installed.
dpkg: error processing apache2-suexec-custom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2-suexec-custom
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install apache2`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4) but it is not going to be installed
           Conflicts: apache2.2-bin but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
           Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
 apache2-suexec-custom : Depends: apache2-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

OK, so here's what I just discovered.  Things seem to work OK with `apache2-suexec-custom` removed.  But I still get this:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libjson0:i386 php-apc php-pear php5 php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-fpm php5-gd php5-imagick php5-imap php5-intl
  php5-ldap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-mysql php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.

user@host:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
```

So what's with the 29 not upgraded?  I'm going to browse around and look for the answer in other questions in the meantime...

SWEET!!!  See DanielSmith-Chatbot's answer for my solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix my locale issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

Comment: Scroll down @CharlesGreen and upvoter.  This server has always had that issue and it's been fine.  I'm trying to fix the dpkg error.

Comment: It's not entirely relevant to your situation, but the answers in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) may help resolve the problem

Comment: See edits to question.

Comment: I'm stumped here.

Comment: Hm.  If it was me....  I'd back up all relevant files and pretty much start over.  I saw [a couple of posts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530872/problem-when-reinstall-apache2-ubuntu-14-04) that basically ended up removing apache2 and then installing it again.

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo apt-get install apache2-bin` ? can you add that to your post

Comment: http://www.km4ayu.com/errors/error2.txt @Neil

Comment: @Daniel - Have you previously installed apache and apache2 ?! - because of package-conflicts there is only one package possible - the next thing is : what output do you have with : sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 --fix-missing ?

Comment: I have apache and apache2 installed already, but I noticed this problem when I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here's what the issue was:

There was a severely messed up package by the name of `apache2-suexec-custom` that needed and hated the same package.  Remove that, and the other packages are now `dist-upgrade`able.  Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ; sudo apt-get upgrade` and everything is upgraded.

Thanks for your help(ish) guys!  Not an expectedd solution, but it worked!

Comment: I am glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ? :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 --fix-missing

or if this was not sufficient, then try to install with package-manager of unity all packages regarding "lamp" as search-word, then all necessary packages are listed.

If above was not of help then this link should contain the answers:

[The following packages have unmet dependencies (apache)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261600/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-apache)

And there is:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: nope, it gives me unmet dependancy.

Comment: @Daniel - check out if apache2 depends on libraries like libc or glibc ?! - wait I look after this ... moment please.

Comment: well, sudo apt-get install libc* still gives me unmet dependencies.  I'm beginning to think that the repo (or one of my repos) may be corrupt.

Comment: OK, see this error: http://www.km4ayu.com/errors/error4.txt

Comment: It appears that apache2-bin is BOTH a dependency and a conflicting package.

Answer (score -1):

please check your locale setting on server

You can see solution in here topic:
[How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

Comment: if you had try to fixed locale but success, please remove sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2-suexec-custom and reinstall it

Comment: the link may be an answer but your post is not

Comment: I tried this and it didn't help this issue.

Comment: But it did, however, fix the locale issue.  But this is an irrelevant answer.